# Tk losing X11 events

Tags: events, mouse, x11, tk-toolkit

I have a canvas on which I have a collection of listboxes and text widgets.
I need to keep track of mouse events, motion, button press/release. I am
simply binding to the 'all' bindtag to catch these events. I have menus
which are posted by button 2 or 3, but I find that sometimes the release
event is not reported.

My approach maybe naive so I'd be happy to hear if there is a better way
to monitor mouse events.

For reference, this is how events are handled:

```
bind  all     <ButtonPress>    {  handleinput %T %W %x %y %X %Y %b  }
bind  all    <ButtonRelease>   {  handleinput %T %W %x %y %X %Y %b  }
bind  all       <Motion>       {  handleinput %T %W %x %y %X %Y %s  }
```

where 'handleinput' sets up a structure describing the current
mouse state.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't mention that I am also using the 'uevent' mechanism as part of a Mealy finite state machine implementation, and I have discovered that that seems to intefere with the X11 events.

I was generating a user event, to trigger dragging of a newly created window, from
the entry selected on the menu. If I avoid doing this, and just placing the created
window on the screen, but button release event from the menu is reported normally.
I haven't looked at the uevent code to see why this is interfering with normal X11
event processing.

I would like to find out what's going on, but as of now, there is no problem with
event delivery.